# Apache Subversion and Sudo - Why can't I resolve this hostname?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, svn, hostname

Okay, I made a mistake and I'll be the first to admit I'm new at this setup. I built a bare bones kit, installed Ubuntu on it, and attempted to set up a source control server for a project some friend and I were going to work on.

Unfortunately, I screwed up. I followed a dodgy tutorial from 2005 and when it didn't work, started mixing and matching trying to get to the source of my problem.

So now I sit before you, a broken and miserable man.

Desperate to escape this annoying echo of 'Unable to resolve host computer.repositoryname.com', I uninstalled apache and subversion. That did not fix it.

Next I tried to edit my /etc/hosts, going so far as to remove the reference to '127.0.1.1 computername'. Still I'm plagued.

I know I messed up, is there any way to track down this wayward bug?

Comment: You didn't identify the source of the error or what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, there's no tracking down this bug but I appreciate the input. I figured I was so close to a clean install anyway I might as well just kill the whole thing and start over. I got it working... somewhat..

Answer (score 1):

edit your /etc/hosts and add these lines :

127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localnet
127.0.0.1 computer.repositoryname.com

Answer (score 0):

Your /etc/resolve.conf should contain something like

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

They should point to some valid DNS servers. For this example I added the google DNS hosts as that should work from everywhere.